# Wordpress blog page

Tags: wordpress

Quick question (quick deadline...I know I can use google).

I'm writing a site on Wordpress w/ a static home page, it has a few pages--I want the 'blog' page to show the wp entries...what's the best way to set this up.

Right now I have a static template for each page (with content rendered), but of course, the blog page doesn't show the posts...

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hey, did I answer your question? Or is there something else you were looking for?

Comment: Yea.  Something funky was going on and I've been super busy!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a Wordpress Page Template by making a page with any name and this comment at the top:

```
/*
Template Name: Blog Enitres
*/
```

Go create a page, use that as the template (there is a selector on the right hand side). Call it whatever and save it. This is your static page.

Then, after that, go down to Settings > Reading and change the 'Home' page to be the page you've created.

Then create an `index.php` and save it. This will be the template for the displayed posts. Create an empty page and select it at the 'Posts Page' in settings.

To learn more about this functionality go [here.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Reading_SubPanel#Pages)

To learn more about the Wordpress loop and how to display entries, visit [codex.wordpress.org](http://codex.wordpress.org/Stepping_Into_Template_Tags)

Comment: Sorry, first answer was mistaken.